# If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible, then so is $A^{-T} + A $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I thought of going at it like this, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where:
$$(A^{-T} + A)x = 0 \implies  A^{-T}x + Ax = 0,$$
then some how show the previous statements imply $x = 0$? Any idea on where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: multiply by $A^T$ and then remember what kind of eigenvalues can have $A^TA$. Or multiply also by $x^T$

Comment: I've never seen notation like this before. Is $A^{-T}$ supposed to be $(A^{-1})^\top$?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, the notation makes use of the fact that the order of the operations does not matter $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$

Comment: I've never seen it in any textbook or article, and I taught linear algebra many dozens of times. Of course I am aware of the identity, @Ninad. Is this notation peculiar to some particular group of mathematicians or geographic location?

Comment: The formula follows from $(AB)^T=B^TA^T.$ When you apply this to $AA^{-1}=I$ you will get $(A^{-1})^TA^T=I.$ Hence $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What formula? Look. I've authored two linear algebra textbooks. I'm fully aware of the identity. I am taking issue with this shorthand notation, not with the concepts.

Comment: @TedShifrin potentially a related question, do you use the phrase codomain or range when teaching about linear maps? There is a pattern I've noticed and I'm wondering if this notation is part of the same pattern.

Comment: @Ninad Mathematicians use range and image (sometimes in confusing ways). "Codomain" appeared in high schools about 20 years ago, and certainly we are aware of this. (Indeed, it may have appeared because some people sloppily use range for the image.) Odd that functorial terminology appears in high school but not in more advanced work.

Comment: @TedShifrin this is a generational issue then, given you have been teaching in California. Another mathematician I spoke with from the midwest thought it could either be a generational or geographic difference. This notation and others in linear algebra in particular has taken hold in my undergrad. Possibly because it is in silicon valley and machine learning is a hot topic these days, so more people who don't have traditional math backgrounds are inclined to write and teach linear algebra texts.

Comment: No. It is not so regionalized in the US, and no, I haven't been teaching in CA. I taught at MIT and at The University of Georgia. I was referring to international conventions. For example, in France they think $0$ is a natural number; we do not. In the meantime, can you cite textbooks that use this ridiculous linear algebra notation?

Comment: @TedShifrin That last generalization is a bit much, I was taught $0$ is a natural number, but I alternate between its inclusion every day. Anyway, it's just a change in times. If you are in San Diego I'll be visiting and happy to meet for tea. We can continue this conversation in a chat.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry. Only now I have noticed a strange notation $A^{-T}.$  In my first comment I was referring to the formula $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How funny. So you missed my entire point, but apparently you now agree with it. :) "strange notation" :)

Comment: @TedShifrin https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136660/lunch I have made a chat

Comment: @TedShifrin It's hard to concentrate on details while watching Roland Garros tennis games and typing answers on mobile phone. :)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc LOL. Well, here in the US we're at the hours where I no longer have (free) access to Roland Garros. Very upsetting. I'm going to miss Alcaraz tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$(A^T)^{-1}+A= (A^{T})^{-1}(I+A^TA)$$ The matrix $A^TA$ has all eigenvalues  real and nonnegative . Hence the eigenvalues of $I+A^TA$ are greater or equal $1.$ In particular this matrix is invertible.